# Python Speech Recognition API response is very slow

Tags: python, speech-recognition, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to develop a french learning app, for which i using Python Speech recognition API to detect what a person has said and then provide him feedback about what he said and how much he had to improve. But the response of the API is very-very slow. What could be the reason.

In one of the answer from the stack overflow, i found to check the input source for my application. I tried both with internal microphone and with my headset microphone but nothing worked. Parallel to this, i am also using CMUSphinx speech API which detect the sound and responses quickly but the accuracy is very poor, so i assume the application is receiving the sound from the microphone.

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    print("Testing Online ASR module. Backend Google Web Speech API..\n")
    while(1):
        print("Speak Now..\n")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio, language='fr-FR')
            response = json.dumps(text, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
            print("You Said: " + str(response))
        except Exception as e:
            print(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

> What could be the reason.

It sends the data on the other side of the planed where data is stored and analyzed by NSA first, only when NSA approves you get the results

> i am also using CMUSphinx speech API which detect the sound and responses quickly but the accuracy is very poor

The right way would be to try something NN-based like Kaldi

Comment: Ok Thanks. But Kaldi did not provide any pre-built model for French language. One has to train it before using it.